# Where to start with cyber security

Tags: security, firewall

Where is a good place to start with cyber security, not necessarily directly related to programming?

I'm looking to cover a wide range of issues:

Fire walls
Networking setup
XSS
SQL Injection
An then other things I don't know I don't know.

My current experience is some programming, some networking. I know to clean my user input before sending to a database, etc.

Where should I start? I'd like some print books to read, but other resources are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're new to the topic and don't yet have specialised in a specific area of computer security, I highly recommend http://www.securitytube.net/. It offers a huge amount of free video based tutorials and other video material you can learn from. Especially you should go for the "Megaprimers" :)

Comment: Kindly go through this link it will help you a lot regarding this question.http://www.career.alnafi.com/cat#a_aid=101&a_bid=d6f11fdd

Comment: http://www.securitytube.net/ <- http be aware